# What Does Kind Constraint mean in Haskell typeclass instance?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When type variables are constrained by classes in Haskell, I understand what that means.

For example, in a function declaration,

```
myFunction :: Foldable f => f a -> b
```

means that f is a type with an instance of Foldable which wraps some other type a.

But what does it mean when a type variable is constrained by a kind?

Consider for instance this definition for Foldable:

```
class Foldable (t :: * -> *) where
```

Also, does the fact that 1 example is from a function definition and the other example is from a class definition make any difference in what the constraint means?

Comment: The kind of `Foldable` is `(Type -> Type) -> Constraint` so I recommend writing `type Foldable :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint` above the declaration (with `StandaloneKindSignatures`) mirroring how `:kind Foldable` outputs the kind. If `Type -> Type` is a `Type`-constructor then `Foldable` is a "`Type`-constructor-class".

Answer (score 2):

`t :: * -> *` is not a constraint, it is a kind annotation. In this case, it is used to remark that `Foldable` can take as arguments type constructors such as `Maybe`, `Identity`, `[]`, or even partially applied ones like `Either Bool` and `(,) String`. By contrast `Foldable Int` and `Foldable [Bool]` would be kind errors.

`t :: * -> *` can be read as "`t` maps types to types".

The point is, when we have `Foldable f` we then use `f` as in `f a`, applying `f` to one argument. If we allow `f = Maybe` we get `Maybe a` which makes sense. If we allowed `f = Int`, we would get `Int a` which is meaningless.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the kind annotation is unnecessary here, as it can be inferred and must be exactly what is specified. There's no polykind shenanigans possible with the types in the `Foldable` class.